# I want to add “aws-iot-device-sdk” to my project

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, mqtt

I want to add “aws-iot-device-sdk” to my project, but I couldn’t find such a plugin for vue js. Have you used it before.

Comment: Please read the doc on how to ask a [good Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It points out the sort of things you need in a question for people to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js

You can install aws iot sdk for javascript.

Comment: I tried all the structures on the page you suggested, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you need to explain more detail